# VueJS method not returning response from Axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promise, vuejs2, axios

Trying to figure this out for awhile now and I know it is something simple but can not seem to figure out the issue. My output is `{}` when I am trying to return a Axios response. When I do not return the entire `axios.post` my output is nothing. But when I `console.log` the data it shows up fine in the console. So I know I am getting the data correctly. Below is my test code. Not sure what I am doing wrong, if anyone has a idea it would be greatly appreciated.

```
<template>
    <div>
        {{ fetch_name('my_name') }}
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
    data() {
        return {
        }
    },
    methods: {
        fetch_name(name) {
            return axios.post('example.com/api/names', {custom: 'SELECT name FROM `names` WHERE name = "'+name+'"'}).then(response => {
                console.log(response.data[0].name)
                return response.data[0].name
            })
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Solution for your case:**

```
<template>
    <div>
        {{ fetch_name('my_name') && result }}
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    import axios from 'axios'
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                result: 'Loading...',
            }
        },
        methods: {
            fetch_name(name) {
                return axios.post('example.com/api/names', {custom: 'SELECT name FROM `names` WHERE name = "'+name+'"'}).then(response => {
                    console.log(response.data[0].name)
                    this.result = response.data[0].name;
                    return response.data[0].name
                })
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

But I think better modify logic something like this:

**Solution for with control name in UI:**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <input v-model="name">
        {{ result }}
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    import axios from 'axios'
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                name: null,
                result: 'Wait for typing',
            }
        },
        watch: {
            name(name) {
                this.result = 'Loading...';
                axios.post('example.com/api/names', {custom: 'SELECT name FROM `names` WHERE name = "'+name+'"'})
                    .then(response => {
                        this.result = response.data[0].name;
                        return response.data[0].name
                    })
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to just return the response. I do not want to assign the response to a variable. I just want to return the response in the function. This data is in table #1 and I am trying to fetch data from table #2 based upon values from table #1. Hope that makes sense. If not, I may just have to redo my question and show a fuller example.

Answer (score 0):

```
return response.data[0].name
```

isn't returning from `fetch_name`  fetch name returns as soon as it does the post....

what you need to do is put the response into your data, then bind to your data, not the method.  When the response to post comes in, it will then trigger the UI update.

Also, sending SQL from the client side seems super dangerous.